# Use of OpenSSL with XCode 7.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, openssl

I'm writing an application that should be cross platform, so my idea is to write the full substrate in C then writing the user's interface related stuffs in Objective-C or other suitable language (i.e. C++ for linux).

For that application I have to use OpenSSL; as documented Apple **dropped** the support of this library since SDK 10.11; as I know OpenSSL should be available until SDK 10.10.

Now my question: I'd like to develop with XCode 7.3 but I'd like that my app should be also backward compatible with reasonably older version of OS X; my idea is that I have to install older SDK across the new XCode 7.3 then choose the right SDK to use under "Build settings" -> "Base SDK".

Can someone point me at a document describing how can I download and install older SDK on new XCode? On Apple Developer website I have found only older release of XCode but it will install a complete old release of XCode...

Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than building with an old SDK, you should build and link with OpenSSL yourself. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW9):

> If your app depends on OpenSSL, you should compile OpenSSL yourself and statically link a known version of OpenSSL into your app.

The version of OpenSSL shipped with OS X is old and out of date, anyway. Apple dropped support for it precisely because they couldn't ship newer versions without breaking backwards compatibility (OpenSSL is not API stable between releases).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer; maybe I used a wrong example; my question is: how to build with old SDK to ensure backward compatibility (beyond the OpenSSL library)?

Comment: The normal approach is to build with the latest version of the SDK, but set the deployment target to the version you're targeting. If you're developing in Swift, the compiler will warn you if you try to use API that doesn't exist on the oldest targeted OS version (without checking for it using `#available()`). If you use ObjC, the compiler isn't so smart about warning you, unfortunately. You can try a tool like [DeployMate](http://www.deploymateapp.com) for that.